# Splash screen requirement iOS app - Portrait

Tags: ios, xcode, splash-screen

I am developing an iPhone app in Xcode 7 which will only open in portrait mode. My question is do I need to provide the launch/splash/default screen also for landscape mode or providing it in the various portrait mode sizes will be sufficient?

Answer (score 2):

I think adding only the portrait ones should work for you. Hope you are using xcassets for managing splash screens. There, You can select the orientations and devices which you want to support. Here is a screenshot.

[image]

NOTE: This is from Xcode 6.4. Hope it's something similar in Xcode 7.

Answer (score 1):

Design the LaunchScreen.xib file to look as your desired splash screen. Set proper constraints to your design elements/views. And thats it! It will appear as expected on any orientation.

For example:
If you want your app logo to appear in the center on app launch as splash screen, set your logo in a image view at center, give constraints for horizontally centering, vertically centering and height and width constraints. Now run the app by keeping simulator in various orientations and your launch screen will appear same in all orientations.

Comment: I have tried to do what @The Rohan Sanap has mentioned above, but in doing so my splash screen image is breaking (blurred), so I think this is not the correct way to do it. It should be done by .xcassets and modifying the info.plist file. This worked for me.

Comment: @bably If your UIImageView size is bigger than the image resolution then it will get blurred (if the UIImageView image mode is set to "Scale to fit"). In such case change the mode to "Center".